# How to resolve this call to ambiguous constructor by making one of the must be explicit?

Tags: c++

In the following code, I construct an instance of `Node` by passing an instance of `Point`. e.g. `Node{{0, 1}};` However, the call to `Node`'s constructor is ambiguous. My guess it that `{0, 1}` can also be comprehended as two `int` representations of `char`, and `{char, char}` also applies to the constructor of `std::string`, in the form of `std::initializer_list<char>`.

I want to preserve the ability to construct `Node` conviniently as `Node{{0, 1}}` while also retain the conversion from `std::string` to `Node`, preferebly in the form of `Node{std::string{"0,1"}}` or something like that. Is there a way to call the constructor that takes a string **only if** I specifies it to do so? or simply disable the `std::string`'s constructor of `std::initializer_list<char>`?

Thanks in adavance.

```
#include <string>

class Point
{
public:
    Point() {};
    Point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
private:
    int x;
    int y;
};

class Node
{
public:
    Node(const std::string& str) {}
    Node(const Point& dot) : dot(dot) {}
private:
    Point dot;
};

int main()
{
    Node{{0, 1}};
    return 0;
}
```

Error Message:

```
/Users/cpp_sandbox.cpp:24:5: error: call to constructor of 'Node' is ambiguous
    Node{{0, 1}};
    ^   ~~~~~~~~
/Users/cpp_sandbox.cpp:16:5: note: candidate constructor
    Node(const std::string& str) {}
    ^
/Users/cpp_sandbox.cpp:17:5: note: candidate constructor
    Node(const Point& dot) : dot(dot) {}
    ^
1 error generated.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: g++ -std=c++11 "/Users/cpp_sandbox.cpp" -o "/Users/cpp_sandbox"]
[dir: /Users]
[path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/SquishCoco/:/Library/TeX/texbin]
```

Comment: Given your requirements, there is no solution.   When you have two constructors, each with arguments that can be constructed using an initialiser list, there will be ambiguity using `Node{{0,1}}`.  Making one or the other `explicit` will not change that (both will still match, and therefore result in ambiguity).    You might try adding a constructor `Node(int, int)` which initialises `dot` using the two `int`s.   That will be used as `Node{0,1}` rather than `Node{{0, 1}}` though.

Comment: Or add a constructor that takes an `initializer_list`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you're out of luck with your current code as both constructors are viable candidates. A solution is to use inheritance instead of aggregation and have `Node` derive from `Point`. You must also explicitly inherit `Point`'s constructor:

```
class Node: public Point
{
public:
    using Point::Point; // constructor inheritance
    Node(std::string str) {}
};
```

Now you can use

```
Node{0, 1}; // note that Node{{0, 1}} will invoke the string ctor
```

and

```
Node{"test"};
```

just fine.

Full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Point
{
public:
    Point() {};
    Point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';}
private:
    int x{};
    int y{};
};

class Node: public Point
{
public:
    using Point::Point;
    Node(const std::string&) {std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';}
};

int main()
{
    Node{0, 1};
    Node{"test"};
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55cf2b46ea3069e6)

If you wonder why now `Node{{0, 1}}` will invoke the `Node::Node(const std::string&)` constructor instead of an ambiguity, that's because the only viable constructor candidate is `Node::Node(const std::string&)` (the other inherited constructor has the signature `Point::Point(int, int)`, so it won't accept an initializer list). Whereas in your original code `Node::Node(const Point&)` would also be a viable constructor due to the implicit conversion from an initializer list to a `Point` (this kind of constructor is called a *conversion constructor*).